# Binary Search tree python. Iterative search

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I was wondering if someone could help me see what i am doing wrong with this search function for a binary search tree. Have to use the iterative version due to the size of data. I keep getting stuck in an infinite while loop when i print out values for debugging. Thanks!

I also get this error:

```
while (word_search.value != user_input) and (word_search.value != None):
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

    def iterative_word_search(current, user_input):
            word_search = current.root
            print("User input value", user_input)
            print("Word Search Value", word_search.value)

            while (word_search.value != None) and (word_search.value != user_input):
                print("While Loop value: ", word_search.value)      
                if(user_input < word_search.value):
                  word_search = word_search.left
    #              print("If statement value: " ,word_search.value)
                elif(word_search.right != None):
                  word_search = word_search.right
                  print("Else statement value: ", word_search.value)
                elif(word_search.value == None):
                    print("Word does not exist")
                    return word_search
            return word_search
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'` means `word_search` variable is `None`. Because the variable is `None`, it won't have `value` attribute and because of that, it will throw this error. This is happening because you're reaching the end of your data structure without finding the value you're asking. In your while loop instead of using `while word_search.value != None` you have to use `while word_search != None`.

Comment: Oh, i see thank you!

Comment: Are you using an iterative approach because you think a recursive approach will be too slow, or because you're concerned that the BST might get out of balance and the recursion stack will become too deep?

Comment: Using iteration because, the BST is unbalanced and it will run deep, overflowing the recursion stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assert that `left` and `right` are not `None` before calling `.value` on them:

Python [lazy](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/creational/lazy_evaluation.py#L22) [evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) of expressions allows you to do this on one line. `if word_search is None or word_search.value is None` will evaluate `word_search`, and if it is `None`, will not evaluate `word_search.value`.

```
def iterative_word_search(current, user_input):

    word_search = current.root

    while True:
        if word_search is None or word_search.value is None:
            print("not found")
            break
        if word_search.value == user_input:
            print("found")
            break
        if(user_input < word_search.value):
            word_search = word_search.left
        elif(word_search.right != None):
            word_search = word_search.right

    return word_search
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, ill try them out!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help!
Solved the problem. It dealt with user input and the files that i read in. 
The files that i read in had a '\N' attached to it. Which is why i kept getting multiple errors and it was not searching the word.

Comment: So essentially this question was solved by another means and the answer did not help you? That means it would not help anyone else. Perhaps you want to delete it.